# Eigenvectors of Stochastic Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution, stochastic-matrices

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Define the matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{(N+1)\times(N+1)}$ by
$$Q_{ij}=\binom{N}{j}\Big(\frac{i}{N}\Big)^j\Big(1-\frac{i}{N}\Big)^{N-j}$$
for all $0\le i,j\le N$.

The sum of each row is $1$, so $(1,\dots,1)$ certainly is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.

Is there a way to directly read the other eigenvectors / eigenvalues of this matrix $Q$?

Comment: Since $Q_{ij} > 0$ for all $0\leq i,j \leq N$, we can apply the [Perron Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices), which give that the eigenvalue 1 is simple, its left and right eigenvectors are the only eigenvectors with strictly positive coefficients, and that the other eigenvalues of $Q$ have absolute value strictly smaller than 1.

Comment: @Shiva I don't think we can apply this theorem here: the matrix is not regular because first and last rows will always be unit vectors. Also, in the case $N=3$, $1$ is a double eigenvalue.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had forgotten about when $i= 0$ or $N$.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Karlin & Taylor vol 1 with me, but I'm pretty sure you can get the Perron root (either exactly or a sharp estimate) for this absorbing chain by viewing it as a martingale and then doing the computations for said martingale